# Calculate remaining year,month and days from current date in android

Tags: android, date

I need to output the difference between 2 dates in years, months and days.
  in my code when subtract  two or three days from 1 year it gives wrong output
  like remaining year,month,days is 0 year / 12 month /3 days
  This is what I do.

```
 Date date = null, date1 = null;
 try {
 date = formatter.parse(SharedPreference.getWeddingDate(getActivity()));
 date1 = formatter.parse(getCurrentTimeStamp());
 targetTime = new GregorianCalendar();
 targetTime.setTime(date);
 currentTime = new GregorianCalendar();
 currentTime.setTime(date1);
   } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } 

 long timeOne = date.getTime();
 long timeTwo = date1.getTime();
 long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
 long delta = (timeTwo - timeOne) / oneDay;
 int year = (int) (delta / 365);
 int rest = (int) (delta % 365);
 int month = rest / 30;
 rest = rest % 30;
```

Comment: simple math and the fact that not all mothns have 30 days

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the stuff around `java.util.Calendar` does not give you any support for the calculation of durations. I know three external libraries available on Android platform which can do this much better and save you some headache. Internally the calculation is not so simple as some people want to make you believe. For example timezones are involved, too.

```
// input
String tz = "Europe/Paris";
java.util.Date d1 = new java.util.Date(0); // or: SharedPreference.getWeddingDate(getActivity());
java.util.Date d2 = new java.util.Date();

// library Threeten-ABP (similar but not identical to Java-8)
LocalDate start = Instant.ofEpochMilli(d1.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of(tz)).toLocalDate();
LocalDate end = Instant.ofEpochMilli(d2.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of(tz)).toLocalDate();
Period p = Period.between(start, end);
System.out.println(p.getYears()); // 45
System.out.println(p.getMonths()); // 11
System.out.println(p.getDays()); // 3
System.out.println(p); // P45Y11M3D

// Joda-Time-Android
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID(tz);
org.joda.time.LocalDate jd1 = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(d1, dtz);
org.joda.time.LocalDate jd2 = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(d2, dtz);
org.joda.time.Period jp = new org.joda.time.Period(jd1, jd2, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
System.out.println(jp.getYears()); // 45
System.out.println(jp.getMonths()); // 11
System.out.println(jp.getDays()); // 3
System.out.println(jp); // P45Y11M3D

// my library Time4A
PlainDate date1 = TemporalType.JAVA_UTIL_DATE.translate(d1).toZonalTimestamp(tz).toDate();
PlainDate date2 = TemporalType.JAVA_UTIL_DATE.translate(d2).toZonalTimestamp(tz).toDate();
Duration<CalendarUnit> duration = Duration.inYearsMonthsDays().between(date1, date2);
System.out.println(duration.getPartialAmount(CalendarUnit.YEARS)); // 45
System.out.println(duration.getPartialAmount(CalendarUnit.MONTHS)); // 11
System.out.println(duration.getPartialAmount(CalendarUnit.DAYS)); // 3
System.out.println(duration); // P45Y11M3D
```

If your wedding date input is in the future then just swap start and end in between-calculations in order to avoid negative durations.